# Is there any way to create email in SMTP server using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, smtp

I already saw nodemailer , node-imap and imap-simple documents , but i can't find a way to connect to a SMTP server and in addition to send and receive mails , a new mail account can be created.
I want something like this :

```
let user_info = {username : 'test@mydomain.com', password : '123456'};
let result = smtpServer.createMailbox(user_info);
console.log(result);
// output : a new user created
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an stmp server using this node js module  smtp-server && mailparser

for more information you can check [this article](https://medium.com/the-innovation/create-an-smtp-server-with-nodejs-5688d8fd882e)

Answer (score -1):

This is one of my implementation for nodemailer in terms of sending out emails

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendEmail = async (options) => {
  // 1) Create a Transporter
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: smtp host address,
    port: smtp port,
    auth: {
      user: EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  // 2) Define the Email Options

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'You name <your email>',
    to: email you are sending to,
    subject: email subject,
    text: your message,
  };

  // 3) Now send email

  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```

Let me know if this helps and don't forget your host address and other credentials should always be in a env file.

Comment: i don't want to send email .... i want to create an email account using node.js
see my example.

Comment: @rouzbehsbz see this https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin